# When I try to logout showing Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

Whenever I click log out this error is showing
[image]

My html is:

[image]

views.py :

[image]

apps urls.py :

[image]

projects urls.py :

[image]

Comment: Just heads up: next time you ask a question, don't include screenshots of the code, but include the actual code. That makes it a lot easier to help with debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the specific path.

try this

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}>Logout</a>
```

Please read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/

also this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing '/logout' in href, use 'url' keyword. For example:

```
{% url 'logout' %}
```